# How can I implement a method, that returns collection & records count

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I build rest api with sails.js.
I want implement pagination in my angularjs frontend.
To do this I should get a list of items along with the total count of items (to calculate pages count), that meet the criteria.

Unfortunately sails.js returns only data list without total records count.

I expect that the server response will look like this:

```
{
 data: [...], // collection data
 count: 193 // records count, that meet the criteria of the request.
}
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implimented a set of blueprints that will return a count in ether the header or the body

https://github.com/randallmeeker/SailsBluePrintActions/tree/master/pagination

here is an example

```
var query = Model.find()
.where( actionUtil.parseCriteria(req) )
.limit( actionUtil.parseLimit(req) )
.skip( actionUtil.parseSkip(req) )
.sort( actionUtil.parseSort(req) );

var metaInfo,
    criteria = actionUtil.parseCriteria(req),
    skip = actionUtil.parseSkip(req),
    limit = actionUtil.parseLimit(req);

Model.count(criteria)
  .exec(function(err, total){
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);

  metaInfo = {
    start : skip,
    end : skip + limit,
    limit : limit,
    total : total,
    criteria: criteria
  };

  res.ok({info: metaInfo, items: matchingRecords});

});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is what I need. By the way it can be improved by parallel `find()` & `count()` calls as @zieglar does.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `async.auto`

```
async.auto(
  count: functuon(callback){
     Model.count(...).exec(callback);
  },
  data: function(callback){
     Model.find(...).exec(callback);
  }
},function(err,results){
  console.log(results.count);
  console.log(results.data);
});
```

Comment: sails.js supports Promises, so async is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model.count` to [count](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/models/count.md) all data that meet the criteria.
Example:

```
// very important here to use the same `criteria` for `find` and `count`
var criteria = {foo: 'bar'};
Model.find(criteria).exec(function (err, found) {
  Model.count(criteria).exec(function (error, count) {
    console.log({ data: found, count: count });
  });
});
```